# How to get the path of an unrelated file with java?

Tags: java, path

I'm running a program that needs to open Google Earth at some point, and I need it's path to open it. Is there any way to get googleearth.exe absolute path from my code (if it's installed in the computer) without having to reach it using a jfilechooser or some sort of file chooser?

Thanks!

Comment: You can recursive search over the directories. [Here is an example]( http://www.mkyong.com/java/search-directories-recursively-for-file-in-java/)

Comment: Or if there is a registry entry you can read this [by using this sample code (chapter 11.9.5)](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0630.html)

Comment: Thanks Jens! The first link is what I was looking for! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find it: As you seem focused only on Windows, you can look for the Program File folder. The name changes depending of the OS language, so I'd try to obtain it from the environment variables:
if you type `set programfiles` in a shell, you'll find something like this:

```
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
```

You can obtain that values with `System.getenv(variableName)`

Then I'd look for the default folder where Google Earth is installed (I don't have it installed, so I'm not sure which name is usually used), and then I'd look for the executable.
You can do it with the `java.io.File` class, using the methods `exists(), isDirectory()` and `listFiles(FileFilter)` to navigate through the file system.